# How to use an enum value in a previous ordinal of the same enum?

Tags: scala, scala-3

(FIG 1) I have the following enum:

```scala
enum Paint(val components: Array[Paint]):
  case Red    extends Paint(Array())
  case Orange extends Paint(Array(Red, Yellow))
  case Yellow extends Paint(Array())
  case Green  extends Paint(Array(Yellow, Blue))
  case Blue   extends Paint(Array())
  case Purple extends Paint(Array(Red, Blue))
  def isPrimary: Boolean = components.isEmpty
```

(FIG 2) When I run the following code:

```scala
@main def helloInteractive(): Unit =
  for
    p <- Paint.values
  do
    println(p.components.mkString(s"${p} is made from ", ", ", ""))
```

(FIG 3) The output I get is:

```
Red is made from 
Orange is made from Red, null
Yellow is made from 
Green is made from Yellow, null
Blue is made from 
Purple is made from Red, Blue
```

(FIG 4) But if I change my enum to be:

```scala
enum Paint(val components: Array[Paint]):
  case Red extends Paint(Array())
  case Yellow extends Paint(Array())
  case Blue extends Paint(Array())
  case Orange extends Paint(Array(Red, Yellow))
  case Green extends Paint(Array(Yellow, Blue))
  case Purple extends Paint(Array(Red, Blue))
  def isPrimary: Boolean = components.isEmpty
```

(FIG 5) I get the correct values in `components`:

```
Red is made from 
Yellow is made from 
Blue is made from 
Orange is made from Red, Yellow
Green is made from Yellow, Blue
Purple is made from Red, Blue
```

I figure that the enum is being created in sequence, therefore something further down the file does not exist yet. Is that correct?

My questions are:

1. How do I get the FIG 5 values while maintaining the enum ordinal from FIG 1?
   I do not want to sort this, I want the enum.ordinal to be as FIG 1.
2. Is this simply a bad idea, and if "yes", why?

This code is me learning the language, it's toy code, don't worry about it being silly or pointless.

Comment: @Dima I'm not asking for a production solution, I am asking for any solutions, if any exist. 

"I don't want to sort this" is a solution constraint, I'd like to see a solution that gives me the ordinal order of FIG 1. Sorting a copy of enum.values afterwards is not what I'm looking to achieve.

If you need a rational reason, curiosity.

Comment: It works if you change the order of the colors to don't refer to initialized values before: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/dB01yBBTSlmiqe8y6UIHig/1

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez as specifically stated in the question, I want to maintain the enum.ordinal shown in FIG 1.

Comment: I'm surprised this does not raise a compilation error. Anyone knows if this would be relevant to raise this as an issue to Scala 3 team?

Comment: Possibly, normally `case object`s are `lazy`... except I am not sure about nested objects (there I think only outermost is lazy), and in Scala 3 parameterless `case`s are not `case object`s but... `val`s. Definitely not `lazy`. I think it might be even expected behavior, and OP should probably replace `Array` with IDK, `Iterator` or `LazyList` for that reason in this code (with a lazy constructor).

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I tried using a lazy val inside the enum to store the Array but result was the same, changing the collection type also made no difference. 

I tried finding out about a "lazy constructor" but did not find anything relevant.

Comment: I am almost certain that you used `lazy val` but initialized it with an eager value then, and that's why you got null. When I mean lazy constructor I was talking about `LazyList` constructor which takes by-name parameters e.g. like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/t342UBFGSqWqWHs6JRROwA/4 (`#::` takes by-name values, as opposed to `LazyList.apply`).

Comment: @GaëlJ the compiler will raise warnings if safe initialization check is enabled by the `-Ysafe-init` option and, as usual, the warnings can be converted to errors by the `-Wconf:any:e` or `-Wconf:msg=non-initialized:e` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The most strightforward and warningless way of having the correct output while maintaining the ordinals is to make the enum parameter called by-name. It is also possible to change its type to `LazyList`, though the current implementation of the latter will generate a lot of warnings if safe initialization check (`-Ysafe-init`) is used:

```scala
    enum Paint(comps: => Array[Paint]):
      case Red    extends Paint(Array())
      case Orange extends Paint(Array(Red, Yellow))
      case Yellow extends Paint(Array())
      case Green  extends Paint(Array(Yellow, Blue))
      case Blue   extends Paint(Array())
      case Purple extends Paint(Array(Red, Blue))
      def isPrimary: Boolean = components.isEmpty
      lazy val components = comps

    import scala.collection.immutable.LazyList.empty
    enum Paint(val components: LazyList[Paint]):
      case Red    extends Paint(empty)
      case Orange extends Paint(Red #:: Yellow #:: empty)
      case Yellow extends Paint(LazyList.empty)
      case Green  extends Paint(Yellow #:: Blue #:: empty)
      case Blue   extends Paint(empty)
      case Purple extends Paint(Red #:: Blue #:: empty)
      def isPrimary: Boolean = components.isEmpty
```

2. Your use case seems legit.

Comment: I like this solution, but just wanted to mention that `LazyList` is a `Seq`, so I would not expose the concrete type in the `enum` definition. IOW, I'd do this: `enum Paint(val components: Seq[Paint]):`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I wanted but this is a workaround:

```scala
enum Paint(private val baseColours: Array[String]):
  case Red    extends Paint(Array())
  case Orange extends Paint(Array("Red", "Yellow"))
  case Yellow extends Paint(Array())
  case Green  extends Paint(Array("Yellow", "Blue"))
  case Blue   extends Paint(Array())
  case Purple extends Paint(Array("Red", "Blue"))
  def isPrimary: Boolean = components.isEmpty
  def components: Array[Paint] = for bc <- baseColours yield Paint.valueOf(bc)
```

Now I get the following result without having to modify the FIG 2 function:

```
Red is made from 
Orange is made from Red, Yellow
Yellow is made from 
Green is made from Yellow, Blue
Blue is made from 
Purple is made from Red, Blue
```